# Generic CSV read and load code

Tags: java, csv

I want to achieve the following in java:

A class having method to read different csv files with different number of columns based on number of parameter provided. For ex :

```
public boolean readAndLoad(String csvPath,String csvFileName, String csvType);
```

Here csvPath and csvFileName are self explanatory but csvType here is to get the table name corresponding to csv. For ex: if csvType is employee that means this csv contains employee data with employee data specific headers.

Now I want to create a common generic method or combination of classes that can perform this and load different csv to different tables. Number of column will differ in each csv.

One possible solution is to check file name manually in method and then getting static header list corresponding to that csv and insert data in table. There will be many if else checks.  Any other solution?

Comment: do you have any sample csv file structures ?

Comment: A Switch case could help?

Comment: The header names should be in the CSV file...

Answer (score 0):

If csvType should match a name of one of your entities I suggest first identifiying that entity from its package:

```
String packageName="com.your.entities";
           ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            URL packageURL;
            ArrayList<String> classesNames = new ArrayList<String>();;
            packageName = packageName.replace(".", "/");
            packageURL = classLoader.getResource(packageName); 
            URI uri = new URI(packageURL.toString());
            File folder = new File(uri.getPath());
                File[] file = folder.listFiles();
                String className;
                for(File actual: file){
                    className = actual.getName();
                    className = className.substring(0, className.lastIndexOf('.'));
                    classesNames.add(className);}
```

Once you got your entities quick look to check csvType if matches one of them, if yes you should get the number of fields for your header, of course fields names as well:

```
 packageName = packageName.replace("/", ".");
                   int headerLengh;
                   String header="";
                   for (String name :classesNames)
                   {
                       if(name.equals(csvType))
                       { headerLengh=Class.forName(packageName+"."+name).getDeclaredFields().length;

                       for (int i=0;i<headerLengh;i++)
                       {
                           header=header+Class.forName(packageName+"."+name).getDeclaredFields()[i].getName()+" ";

                       }}}
```

Once your csvType matched an entity, you have the header and the table, you can read it simply or load it into table (which you know now ) via your own logic or methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to get the job done. It's packed with features and very fast. If you need to map your data into objects of specific classes, you can declare classes with annotations on their attributes that indicate what are the field names/positions. Hierarchies of classes are also well supported if you need.

If you just need to provide headers to each possible input, you'll find a `setHeaders` method that allows you to assign any list of headers to an input. You can also call a `selectFields` method to choose which fields to read and which to ignore.